# PXF Hive Plugin, to select only the columns selected in the query

Tags: hive, external, hawq

Is there a way to PXF select only the column used in the query, apart from Hive partition filtering.

I have data stored in Hive-ORC format and using pxf external table to execute queries in HAWQ. The biggest tables are stored in Hive and we cannot make another copy of data in HAWQ.

Thanks--

P.S - Does the query optimizer collect stats on external tables in HAWQ 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

You can always run a `select foo from bar` type query on external tables in HAWQ. However, if your question is whether PXF actually does column projection to avoid reading all the columns then the answer is No. Currently PXF will read all columns from an ORC file and return the records to HAWQ which then does the projection filtering on its end. However, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ-583, is actively being worked on and should be released in an upcoming version of HAWQ which will pushdown column projections down to ORC to improve read performance of ORC files

Yes, the query optimizer does collect statistics on external tables, this is also handled by PXF. However, this is only for some data sources: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ-44

Comment: One potential work-around for the columnar functionality would be to use something like gplink to "federate" the query directly to Hive. Although the projection will happen at read-time, you'll lose the benefits of data node parallelism offered by PXF. For a wide ORC table, this could be a worthwhile tradeoff, but it is solely dependent on your table+column width.